# How to Remove/Hide unwanted address fields

Tags: checkout, module, custom, shipping-address

I've looked everywhere for an answer to my question.
I'm pretty new to Magento.

For the shipping-address page of my site, I need to have all of the fields removed.
My plan is to have them removed and use the module I purchased to display the fields I want. And it does display everything I want so far. But the original stock checkout fields still remain.

I know you have to override the checkout with a template I believe. I have the skeleton custom module already made. So far I have a module with a *Block, etc,* and ***view*** directory, my ***composer.json*** and my ***registration.php***. I also have a ***checkout_index_index.html*** file that I want to use to make my custom checkout page.
I'm just confused on how they tie together. And how I could finally get this to work after spending hours on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have to override this `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these code to get a hint:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

These codes remove company field. You have to make a similar change to your code in **shipping.html** file to hide your desired fields.